# Anaconda Navigator won't launch after installing gradio

Tags: anaconda, gradio

anaconda navigator won't launch after installing gradio,
whenever I reset the navigator launches just fine,
but after installing gradio it won't launch.

does it have something to do with mulipart package?

after re-installing or restarting it works fine,

activate root
conda update -n root conda
conda update --all

I did this and tried to run my notebook, it said gradio package note found,
so I installed it again and now the navigtor won't lauch

Jupyter notebook works fine.

Comment: Have you tried creating an environment and installing gradio and all other packages you need for this project in there. That way, you cannot mess up your base env